# A different approach to a common question

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

A unit stick is randomly broken into 3 pieces, it is given that these three pieces can make a triangle, what is the expected length of the medium-sized piece?

This a question we are all familiar with and anyone who has seen it anywhere/solved it knows that the expected length of the medium piece is $\frac{5}{18}$, we reach this conclusion by using $E(L+M+S) = 1$, and we know we can calculate $E(L)$ and $E(S)$, so we just use $E(M) = 1-E(L)-E(S)$ to get our answer, is there any way we can solely calculate the $E(M)$ without calculating the other two values?

$L$: Length of the longest part

$S$: Length of the smallest part

$M$: Length of the medium part

Thank you :)

Comment: Hey, as I wrote I want to find out the expected length of the medium sized part without calculating the expected value of the longest and the shortest. This question doesn't answer my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy approach.

Let's arrange the segments from smallest to largest. Let the three segments be $x$, $x+y$ and $x+y+z$.
Now sum of all segments $= 1$
$\implies 3x + 2y + z = 1$; 
with the conditions: $x\geqslant 0,y \geqslant 0,z \geqslant 0$
$\text{and } x \leqslant 1/3 , y \leqslant 1/2, z \leqslant 1$.

for normalisation, let $n$ be a quantity $\leqslant 1/6$, then,

$$\frac{x}{2} \leqslant \frac{1}{6} , \frac{y}{3} \leqslant \frac{1}{6}, \frac{z}{6} \leqslant \frac{1}{6}$$

$x$ can be chosen randomly among a pool from $[0,2n]$, $y$ be chosen randomly from a pool $[0,3n]$ and $z$ from a pool $[0,6n]$ where $(x,y,z,n)$ $\in$ $\mathbb R$.

Therefore we can say:

Expected value of $x = n$, expected value of $y = 1.5n$ and expected value of $z = 3n$. 
Expected length of middle segment  = $x+y = 2.5n$
Expected total length  = $3x+2y+z = 9n$
The the expected length of middle segment is

$(x+y)/(3x+2y+z)= 2.5/9= 5/18 $.

Comment: I think you should replace y and z with c1, c2, the approach is really interesting!

Comment: Hey, in this one, are you implying that Expected length of the smallest piece be x/(3x+2y+z) = 1/9 ? And that for the longest will be: 11/18 ?

Comment: @ParthLohomi yes

Comment: Okay, I got the same answers using my approach

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is using geometric probability. Though it may involve some integrals, it is a very general approach!

First, we can note that we can express the space of stick pieces using two variables $x$ and $y$, for breaking point $1$ and breaking point $2$, respectively. Then we can note that this situation is symmetric so WLOG we can let $y>x$.

Then the three stick lengths will be

1. $\min(x,y)=x$
2. $\max(x,y)-\min(x,y)=y-x$
3. $1-\max(x,y)=1-y$

Now, the middle stick will thus be the median $\text{median}(x,y-x, 1-y)$, and our probability would initially be defined by the triangle formed by the lines $y>x$, $y=1$, and $x=0$.

However, as we are given the lengths form a triangle, this must mean no two of the lengths can sum to less than the third length. Another way to see this is that each length must be less than $1/2$ (as the lengths must sum to $1$). Thus, we can define our probability space of triangle lengths via

1. $x < 1/2$
2. $y-x < 1/2$
3. $1-y < 1/2$

To find the expected value we can now integrate the middle length over this region and divide by the area of the this region as follows:
$$\mathbb{E}(M) = \frac{1}{1/8}\int_{1/2}^1\int_{y-1/2}^{1/2} \text{median}(x,y-x,1-y)\ dx\ dy$$
The bounds here are achieved by rewriting 3. as $y > 1/2$, 2. as $x > y-1/2$, and 1. as itself, or alternatively looking at the picture below (the purple region is where triangle inequality is satsified).[image: probability space]
Now this is a bit of a strange integral, so we will need to separate it into a few regions based on when $x$ i the median, when $y-x$ is the median, and when $1-y$ is the median length. Hopefully this makes sense, and if you need more help with this process, just comment!

Comment: Yep, I'll clarify that!